# How to get instance by base type from IServiceProvider.GetServices<T> (aspnet core DI)?

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.2

I would like to get all services that inherite `MyBaseClass` from IServiceProvider:

```
var myBaseClassInstances = serviceProvider.GetServices<MyBaseClass>();
```

I can register all derived classes as:

```
services.AddSingleton<InheritedFromMyBaseClass>();
services.AddSingleton<MyBaseClass>(serviceProvider => serviceProvider.GetService<InheritedFromMyBaseClass>());
```

Are there any ways to do this with one registration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependency injection that comes with .NET Core does not allow that out of the box, you need to roll out your custom extension method.

Comment: Do you have an example of a such an extension method?

Comment: Not really, you would need to implement something to obtain a name from a registration.

Answer (score 1):

You could register your services like this:

```
services.AddSingleton<MyBaseClass, ImplementationA>();
services.AddSingleton<MyBaseClass, ImplementationB>();
services.AddSingleton<MyBaseClass, ImplementationC>();
```

or

```
services.AddTransient<MyBaseClass, ImplementationA>();
services.AddTransient<MyBaseClass, ImplementationB>();
services.AddTransient<MyBaseClass, ImplementationC>();
```

depending of their scope...

```
var instances = serviceProvider.GetServices<MyBaseClass>();
```